# Purchased Theme to Custom Made Theme?

Tags: theme-development, themes

I bought a theme from Themeforest and now I would like to convert it to a custom made theme.  I was creating the theme with the Underscores theme: http://underscores.me/ but how do I keep the same custom post types in the next theme?

Is this less time consuming than recoding the purchased theme?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the custom post types to a plugin. They should never be part of a theme for exactly the reason you asked here. :)

In your theme add just the needed template files, but not the code for post type registration.

Comment: is there any good reference on how to do this, I have made a few theme's now alwasy with custom types. A lot of the times the same, I would find it interesting if I could move this into a plugin.

Comment: You need just a plugin header and the registration function. Something like this: https://gist.github.com/889394

Comment: oh ok, so I can just put any code I would normally put in functions into a 'plugin-codefile' and it will work when plugin is activated just like it would if it were in functions.php . That's a great bit of information, I will try this out this evening. Thanks and sorry for the sort of 'off-topic'

Comment: @toscho this seems like a great idea thanks! would be a great way to make sure things are working correctly in the future

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to simply create a child theme - it would definitely be less work, and you could extend anything that currently exists in the theme you purchased.

Before you do this, I would suggest installing the [Theme Authentication Checker (TAC)](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/tac/) and run it through the theme you purchased. If there are a lot of errors, then chances are in the future when you update WordPress, their code could indeed break. If that's the case, I'd suggest using their resources and re-code it - better to start off properly, than have to fix it in 6 months when the code isn't fresh.

That said, developing your own themes is always preferable, if you have the ability and knowledge of WordPress best practices.

As for retaining the custom post types, and other aspects of the them you purchased, it totally depends on the developer's style. Your best bet is to load the site into an IDE with site-wide search, and look for `register_post_type` and any other syntax that creates the content you want to bring to your custom-made _s theme.

Hope this helps! :)

[Tutorial on Child Themes](http://designisphilosophy.com/24-days-of-wordpress/creating-a-wordpress-child-theme-the-smart-way/)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I didn't think about a child theme since I have never created one before, but if I do create a child theme would it be similar to starting from scratch or does the Parent theme have all the elements loaded? I think I'm leaning more towards creating my own theme just have to think about everything.. The Custom Post Types were actually created with some Post Type Creator within the theme so I'm not sure I can search for `register_post_type` but I will try that out soon and let you know how it turns out.  Thanks!

Comment: I'll attach a great tutorial above on how to create a child theme. Essentially it's uses the original theme first, then overwrites with your child theme. Example: if you have header.php in your main theme, but want to alter it - copy it into your child them, and make there alterations there.